# Opening second responsive frame that runs another thread

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, python-multithreading

i have an application which runs nice. There is a button on the application which should open a new window and run an ssh command in the background. The outpot of that command should then be written into the window.

All this while keeping the main window repsonsive and running some background task in itself.

This is what i have:

```
def startGetJobSSH(self,event=None):
    self.threadList.append(threading.Thread(target=statusWindow,args=[self]))
    self.threadList[len(self.threadList)-1].start()
```

This is the function from my main programm. It starts "statusWindow" as a new thread.

```
class statusWindow(wx.Frame):

FLAG_KILL_THREAD = False

def __init__(self,parent):
    LogEntry("statusWindow Class created")
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent=parent.frame)
    self.stillrunning=True
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE,self.onQuit)
    self.panel = wx.Panel(self,size=(600,600))
    self.topLevelSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.panel.SetSizer(self.topLevelSizer)
    self.statusTextBox = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, style=wx.NO_BORDER | wx.TE_MULTILINE |
                                     wx.TE_DONTWRAP | wx.HSCROLL | wx.TE_READONLY,size=(500,500))
    self.topLevelSizer.Add(self.statusTextBox)
    self.okButton = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Ok')
    self.okButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onQuit)
    self.topLevelSizer.Add(self.okButton,0,wx.ALL,5)
    #self.Fit()


    self.Show()

    self.mythread = threading.Thread(target=self.trysomething)
    self.mythread.start()



    while self.mythread.is_alive():
        time.sleep(0.1)
        wx.GetApp().Yield()
        self.statusTextBox.AppendText("Running\n")
        continue


def trysomething(self,event=None):
    for i in range(100):
        self.statusTextBox.AppendText("Number: "  +  str(i) + "\n")
        time.sleep(0.1)

def onQuit(self,event=None):
    self.FLAG_KILL_THREAD = True
    self.Hide()
    print("joining")
    self.mythread.Join(5)
    print("joined")
    self.Destroy()
```

This is the class. The Layout is not done and doesnt really matter. What matters is two things. First of the thread doesnt seem to do anything. The text doesnt get appended in it despite me starting a thread that should write stuff into the textbox.

Second is that the Frame is not responsive like it should be. While hovering over it the mous turns into "loading" circle which indicates that the window is working.

Comment: You are attempting to load a wxPython window as a `Thread`, then starting it, even though the `statusWindow` class starts the thread itself. I'm surprised it runs at all. Simply calling the `statusWindow(self)` should enough to get it going, although you'll probably have to change to `wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent)` dropping the `=parent,frame` part.

Comment: Thanks. Your comment actually pushed me in the right direction. And now that you said it ofc its wrong trying to start the new window as a thread. The whole point of the mainapp is to handle all windows. If you want you can change the call and post it as answer then i will mark it.

Comment: It was just a bit of brain fog, I'll leave it as a comment, glad to help.